# How could I convert elastic search query with elasticsearcg-rails DSL

Tags: elasticsearch

I got this Exception , it seems show me there are exception in the query statements.

However, I could figure out what should I modify, any idea?

```
(pry) output error: #<Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::BadRequest: [400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_parsing_exception","reason":"[_na] query malformed, no field after start_object","index":"flights","line":1,"col":11}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"flights","node":"mVtcYMIfRxOBeqWvMbShhA","reason":{"type":"query_parsing_exception","reason":"[_na] query malformed, no field after start_object","index":"flights","line":1,"col":11}}]},"status":400}>
```

## this is the original elastic search, it works and I got the results

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "analyze_wildcard": true,
          "query": "total_price_twd: [10 TO 10000]"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "departure_at": {
                  "gte": 1452164239142,
                  "lte": 1457348239142,
                  "format": "epoch_millis"
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "must_not": []
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "3": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "departure_at",
        "interval": "1d",
        "time_zone": "Asia/Shanghai",
        "min_doc_count": 1,
        "extended_bounds": {
          "min": 1452164239141,
          "max": 1457348239141
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

## This is what I'm designing query DSL with elasticsearch-rails

```
Q_PARAMS = {
 "size":0,
 "query":{
    "filtered":{
       "query":{
          "query_string":{
             "analyze_wildcard":true,
             "query":"total_price_twd:   [10 TO 10000]"
          }
       },
       "filter":{
          "bool":{
             "must":[
                {
                   "range":{
                      "departure_at":{
                         "gte":1452164239142,
                         "lte":1457348239142,
                         "format":"epoch_millis"
                      }
                   }
                }
             ],
             "must_not":[
             ]
          }
       }
    }
 },
 "aggs":{
    "3":{
       "date_histogram":{
          "field":"departure_at",
          "interval":"1d",
          "time_zone":"Asia/Shanghai",
          "min_doc_count":1,
          "extended_bounds":{
             "min":1452164239141,
             "max":1457348239141
          }
       }
    }
 }
}

def self.es_search
  __elasticsearch__.search(
    {
      query: Q_PARAMS,
      size: 200
    }
  )
end
```

## Result from Elasticsearch search

```
{
  "took": 23,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 12991,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "3": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key_as_string": "2016-01-07T00:00:00.000+08:00",
          "key": 1452096000000,
          "doc_count": 46
        },
        ...
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

## Log from Elasticsearch server

```
elasticsearch_1 | [2016-03-07 11:05:04,273][INFO ][rest.suppressed          ] //flights/flight/_search Params: {index=flights, type=flight}
elasticsearch_1 | Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[mVtcYMIfRxOBeqWvMbShhA][flights][0]: RemoteTransportException[[Payback][172.17.0.3:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[failed to parse search source [{"query":{"size":0,"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"query_string":{"analyze_wildcard":true,"query":"total_price_twd:   [10 TO 10000]"}},"filter":{"bool":{"must":[{"range":{"departure_at":{"gte":1452164239142,"lte":1457348239142,"format":"epoch_millis"}}}],"must_not":[]}}}},"aggs":{"3":{"date_histogram":{"field":"departure_at","interval":"1d","time_zone":"Asia/Shanghai","min_doc_count":1,"extended_bounds":{"min":1452164239141,"max":1457348239141}}}}},"size":200}]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[_na] query malformed, no field after start_object]; }{[mVtcYMIfRxOBeqWvMbShhA][flights][1]: RemoteTransportException[[Payback][172.17.0.3:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[failed to parse search source [{"query":{"size":0,"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"query_string":{"analyze_wildcard":true,"query":"total_price_twd:   [10 TO 10000]"}},"filter":{"bool":{"must":[{"range":{"departure_at":{"gte":1452164239142,"lte":1457348239142,"format":"epoch_millis"}}}],"must_not":[]}}}},"aggs":{"3":{"date_histogram":{"field":"departure_at","interval":"1d","time_zone":"Asia/Shanghai","min_doc_count":1,"extended_bounds":{"min":1452164239141,"max":1457348239141}}}}},"size":200}]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[_na] query malformed, no field after start_object]; }{[mVtcYMIfRxOBeqWvMbShhA][flights][2]: RemoteTransportException[[Payback][172.17.0.3:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[failed to parse search source [{"query":{"size":0,"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"query_string":{"analyze_wildcard":true,"query":"total_price_twd:   [10 TO 10000]"}},"filter":{"bool":{"must":[{"range":{"departure_at":{"gte":1452164239142,"lte":1457348239142,"format":"epoch_millis"}}}],"must_not":[]}}}},"aggs":{"3":{"date_histogram":{"field":"departure_at","interval":"1d","time_zone":"Asia/Shanghai","min_doc_count":1,"extended_bounds":{"min":1452164239141,"max":1457348239141}}}}},"size":200}]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[_na] query malformed, no field after start_object]; }{[mVtcYMIfRxOBeqWvMbShhA][flights][3]: RemoteTransportException[[Payback][172.17.0.3:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[failed to parse search source [{"query":{"size":0,"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"query_string":{"analyze_wildcard":true,"query":"total_price_twd:   [10 TO 10000]"}},"filter":{"bool":{"must":[{"range":{"departure_at":{"gte":1452164239142,"lte":1457348239142,"format":"epoch_millis"}}}],"must_not":[]}}}},"aggs":{"3":{"date_histogram":{"field":"departure_at","interval":"1d","time_zone":"Asia/Shanghai","min_doc_count":1,"extended_bounds":{"min":1452164239141,"max":1457348239141}}}}},"size":200}]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[_na] query malformed, no field after start_object]; }{[mVtcYMIfRxOBeqWvMbShhA][flights][4]: RemoteTransportException[[Payback][172.17.0.3:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[failed to parse search source [{"query":{"size":0,"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"query_string":{"analyze_wildcard":true,"query":"total_price_twd:   [10 TO 10000]"}},"filter":{"bool":{"must":[{"range":{"departure_at":{"gte":1452164239142,"lte":1457348239142,"format":"epoch_millis"}}}],"must_not":[]}}}},"aggs":{"3":{"date_histogram":{"field":"departure_at","interval":"1d","time_zone":"Asia/Shanghai","min_doc_count":1,"extended_bounds":{"min":1452164239141,"max":1457348239141}}}}},"size":200}]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[_na] query malformed, no field after start_object]; }
elasticsearch_1 |   at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction.onFirstPhaseResult(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:228)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try wrapping it in a `body` key and executing it straight from the `Client` object:

```
Q_PARAMS = {
  size: 200,
  query: {
     filtered: {
       query: {
          query_string: {
             analyze_wildcard: true,
             query: "total_price_twd:   [10 TO 10000]"
          }
       },
       filter: {
          bool: {
             must: [
                {
                   "range":{
                      "departure_at":{
                         "gte":1452164239142,
                         "lte":1457348239142,
                         "format":"epoch_millis"
                      }
                   }
                }
             ],
             "must_not":[
             ]
          }
       }
    }
 },
 "aggs":{
    "3":{
       "date_histogram":{
          "field":"departure_at",
          "interval":"1d",
          "time_zone":"Asia/Shanghai",
          "min_doc_count":1,
          "extended_bounds":{
             "min":1452164239141,
             "max":1457348239141
          }
       }
    }
 }
}

def self.es_search
  __elasticsearch__.client.search(body: Q_PARAMS)
end
```